# Selenium- Tag traversal Xpath for facebook First name not working

Tags: facebook, selenium, xpath

```
<div id="reg_form_box" class="large_form">
<div class="clearfix _58mh">
<div class="mbm _3-90 lfloat _ohe">
<div id="u_0_0" class="_5dbb">
<div class="uiStickyPlaceholderInput uiStickyPlaceholderEmptyInput">
<div class="placeholder" aria-hidden="true">First name</div>
<input id="u_0_1" class="inputtext _58mg _5dba _2ph-" data-type="text"     name="firstname" aria-required="1" placeholder="" aria-label="First name" aria-controls="js_0" aria-haspopup="true" role="null" aria-describedby="js_w" aria-invalid="true" type="text"/>
</div>
<i class="_5dbc img sp_beZQzZ7Rg6Q sx_5ca7f2"/>
<i class="_5dbd img sp_beZQzZ7Rg6Q sx_9c246c"/>
</div>
```

Above is the code for which i want to write Xpath using tag name traversal. Here is the xpath i have made

```
"//div[@id='reg_form_box']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/input"
```

Please suggest what's wrong here and how can i correct the same. Website is Facebook and field is First name on homepage.

Comment: This XPath is far from being the best choice but it works for me. Your issue might be a different one. And, be sure to stay on the legal side (see the facebook terms of use).

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow then to scrape them. Use the API

Answer (score 0):

Ideally unless you have a case of multiple modes that match the same xpath, you don't have to traverse through the entire hierarchy.

This will work:

```
//input[@name='firstname']
```